# Symfony paramaters explode on comma returns a single entry

Tags: php, symfony, explode

Fetching parameters from parameters.yml and using `explode(",", $param)` on it doesn't work as expected.

*Parameters.yml*

```
parameterIWant : 50,58,14,39,78,28
```

It returns a single array with `505814397828` instead of an array of all the numbers split.

I wish to get an array from the parameter string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Symfony returns an float `5058143978.28` and the explode returns a single item.

Two solutions :

Put quotation mark around the parameter

```
parameterIWant : "50,58,14,39,78,28"
```

Or use another split character such as ;

```
parameterIWant : 50;58;14;39;78;28
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```yaml
parameterIWant:
  - 50
  - 58
  - 14
  - 39
  - 78
  - 28
```

In your php code :

```php
/** @var array $parametersIWant **/
$parametersIWant = $this->getParameter('parameterIWant');
$stringParameter = implode(',', $parametersIWant);
```

it will display "50,58,14,39,78,28" as a string

Comment: I do not wish to get a string at the end ... I wish to get an array from a string in parameters

Comment: I understand, sorry for misunderstood. However i think that having array in your parameter (whatever you want as final) is a better way. Here, you don't have a lot of number, but imagine with time and evolution, a lot of numbers could be added, it will be harder to treat them :).